# How can connect to the mysql with ionic

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework

We're working on mobile app in ionic and we can't find how to insert mysql to ionic for example we have register interface we can input all informations but how can we save to the sqlserver thanks.

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is a front end framework. To interface with Sql Server you will need some kind of backend to take care of interfacing with the database.

The .NET framework which is a C# backend, has terrific Sql Server integration given it is all a Microsoft product.

If you are looking for backend to be more or less taken care of I would recommend [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1001467%20%7C%20Firebase*%20Brand%20GENERIC%20%7C%20US%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20Desk%2BTab%2BMobile%20%7C%20Text%20%7C%20BKWS%20%5B2017%5D&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkfX8mdKv1gIVnY-zCh0t6AZqEAAYASAAEgKCW_D_BwE) which is a back end as a service. It doesn't use Sql Server out of the box but can be used together.

Comment: we need a large database for our database cause of it we need mysql but thanks again :)

Comment: @MustafaK. Be careful, MySQL and SQL Server are two different products. They both perform generally the same tasks but its easy to confuse them.